# CSS: height % parent with min height % children (relatively positioned)

Tags: css, height, percentage

So, I might in fact be overthinking this entirely and should scrap min-height, but I am currently have the following HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
      <div id='nav'>
      </div>
      <div id='content'>
          <div id='main-content'>
                <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
                <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
                <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
          </div>
          <div id='side-bar'>
                 <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
                <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
                <div class='stuff'>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     position:relative;
 }

#nav {
     width:1000px;
     height:40px;
     position:fixed;
         top:0;
}

  #content{
     width:100%;
     min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
     min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
     min-height: calc(100% - 40px);
     margin-top:40px;
 }

#main-content{
     background:#e1e1e1;
     width:600px;
     height:100%;
     position:relative;

}

 #side-bar{
         background:#d1d1d1;
         width:400px;
         height:100%;
         position:absolute;
             right:0;

    }
```

I'm just looking for a simple two column layout, with the columns different colors -> always at least 100% height so that they fill out the screen. I set to min-height since if the content within overflows, I'd like the height of the parent 'content' div (and subsequently the 'container' div) to grow and allow the page to scroll.

Right now though... it seems min-height % doesn't work when within a parent with a height %. Let alone trickling down further.

Maybe I'm just approaching this entirely wrong though? I don't know.

Comment: I don't see `height: 100%;` on `html` and `body`. Could be the problem, but the positioning on `nav` and `#side-bar` is throwing me off.

Comment: I just did a short hand HTML/CSS here, so didn't add body or html. However, I do have both of these set at 100% for height and width.

Comment: add a fiddle? FWIG it should work (kinda), but I'm not looking at the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the parent element height first before you declare the % height of the child element.

Comment: try to do the height in px

Comment: I need to have my height variable with screen height. So the containing div is 100%. It's child is both the nav bar which does have fix pixel height, but the content div is simply 100% height less the nav bar pixels, but min-height because it should grow if content within grows. The main area and sidebar area are then both 100% of their parent (100% less 84px).